# Remove specific character from string (SQL Server 2012)

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

I have a view from which I want to remove a specific character in one of the columns. Specifically the character 'B' from the 'Fund' column below.

[image]

I tried using the following version of `TRIM`

```
  SELECT 
       TRIM('B' FROM [Port_Ticker]) as "Fund"
      ,[BENCH_Ticker] as "Index ID"
      ,format(cast([VALUE_DATE] as Date),'dd/MM/yyyy') as "Updat"
      ,([Port_Risk_Contrib] / 10000000) as "StDev Fund"
      ,([Active_risk_contrib] / 10000000) as "TE"
      ,([BENCH_RISK_CONTRIB] / 100) as "StDev BM"
  FROM [DM_PORTFOLIO_ANALYSIS].[basedata].[PortfolioRiskFigures]
  where [BLOCK_FACTOR] = 'Total'
  and [Port_ticker] = 
  'B1023'
  order by [VALUE_DATE] asc
```

Which gives me the error

> Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 3.
>    Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'FROM'.

Comment: I recommend against `FORMAT`, it's an awfully slow function. You would be far better off using `CONVERT` and a [style code](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/cast-and-convert-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017#date-and-time-styles). So `format(cast([VALUE_DATE] as Date),'dd/MM/yyyy')` could be change to `CONVERT(varchar(10),[VALUE_DATE],103)` (assuming that `VALUE_DATE` is a `datetime` datatype, which I see no reason  why it would be as it's storing a date. :) )

Comment: `TRIM` is available since SQL Server 2017. So your version doesn't support `TRIM`: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/trim-transact-sql

Comment: Example of how slow `FORMAT` is compared to `CONVERT`: [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=b9efee2f0b258d54b0588202544f964d)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `replace()` to do this. In this case it will search for `'B'` and replace it with an empty string -> `''`. Please note that this function will replace all `'B'` from this column.

```
 SELECT 
       REPLACE([Port_Ticker], 'B', '') as "Fund"
      ,[BENCH_Ticker] as "Index ID"
      ,format(cast([VALUE_DATE] as Date),'dd/MM/yyyy') as "Updat"
      ,([Port_Risk_Contrib] / 10000000) as "StDev Fund"
      ,([Active_risk_contrib] / 10000000) as "TE"
      ,([BENCH_RISK_CONTRIB] / 100) as "StDev BM"
  FROM [DM_PORTFOLIO_ANALYSIS].[basedata].[PortfolioRiskFigures]
  where [BLOCK_FACTOR] = 'Total'
  and [Port_ticker] = 'B1023'
  order by [VALUE_DATE] asc
```

Answer (score 3):

The [`Trim()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/trim-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) function was introduced in 2017 version.
Naturally, you can't use it in older versions.

There are several ways this can be done, by using `replace` as M. Kanarkowski demonstrated in his answer, or any of these options:

[`stuff`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/stuff-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017): `STUFF([Port_Ticker], 1, 1, '') As "Fund"`,
[`substring`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/substring-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017): `SUBSTRING([Port_Ticker], 2, LEN([Port_Ticker])) As "Fund"`
[`Right`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/right-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017): `RIGHT([Port_Ticker], LEN([Port_Ticker])-1) As "Fund"`